# Make selected column bold and unbold other column in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Excel Sheet with Macros in it. I want to change the entire column bold when I click on associated button. The click should also unbold all other bold columns.

```
Public row As Integer, VerticalRange As Range
Sub Sort_Macro_C()
Set VerticalRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b9:b1000")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c9:c1000").Font.Bold = True
row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(VerticalRange) + 10
Range(Cells(10, 2), Cells(row, 16)).sort Key1:=Range("C9"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:= _
    xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
End Sub
```

The above code bolds the entire column but I am not figuring out how to unbold the remaining columns. Any help is appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Font.Bold = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C9:C1000").Font.Bold = True
```

First it will unbold anything, and then it bolds only the `Range("C9:C1000")`. If you do not have merged cells, you may use one of the following two:

- `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C").Font.Bold = True`
- `Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(3).Font.Bold = True`

Concerning that you are working with `Selection`, if you want to bold the all the column of given selection, you may use this:

```
Selection.EntireColumn.Font.Bold = True
```